# color scale to illustrate the temperature, Python script

Tags: python, colors, scale, blender, particles

I make an astronomical visualization, which illustrates a birth of a planet from a cloud of particles (which i have over 130.000). Each particle, besides xyz-coordinate, has also a temperature value.

Is it possible to code it like Temperature minimum is green, Temperature maximum is magenta. Dear script, color my particles in scale between green and magenta?

I am working with Python (Blender).

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with Blender, but assuming you can assign RGB values, this loop will fade from green to magenta:

```
counter = 130000        # number of particles in your cloud
change = 256 / counter  # in-/de-crement for each particle

rgb = [0, 255, 0]       # starting colour (green)

for i in range(0, counter):
    rgb = [rgb[0] + change, rgb[1] - change, rgb[2] + change]
    print("i: %04d; R: %03d, G: %03d, B: %03d" % (i, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])) # for debugging only, floats to integers for legibility
```

There's probably more sophisticated solutions, but hopefully that'll get you started.

Comment: FYI: This will only spread the colour variation across a range, not associate any of the transitional colour with a specific temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Should I say before t min (32.668837340451788) is green, t max (129.20671163699313) is magenta? So that the script knows, is the value "cold" or "warm".
First particle for example will be almost magenta.

Here are 4 first particles:

1. 5.28964162682e+14 5.62257206698e+13 -2.9525300544e+14 128.332184907
2. 5.23680422449e+14 9.33982452199e+13 -2.9525300544e+14 128.336966138
   3  5.15787732694e+14 1.3010546441e+14 -2.9525300544e+14 128.346633243
3. 5.05325414399e+14 1.66164504722e+14 -2.9525300544e+14 128.355079501